# Recognize hand drawn shape in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-recognition, template-matching, shape-recognition

I have the following task: recognize a set of simple hand-drawn shapes on a sheet of paper from a still image (not a video stream), so they might not be exactly identically pixelwise.

Those shapes are basically symbols for doors, windows, etc. in a floor plan (see attached image), so they might be slightly scaled or rotated (90° steps).
There are about 5 different ones.

So far I came across **SIFT** (and its OpenCV-variants **SURF** and **ORB**) as well as a **cascaded classifier to recognize haar-like features**.

For SIFT there seem to be **too little key points** in such a shape whereas I did not manage to get the haar-trained cascaded classifier to work. Also, a cascaded classifier seems a bit heavy for recognizing such simple shapes, no?

---

Does anyone of you have any good hints or alternative approaches? Or maybe you even have a snippet of code lying around which I can use?

[image: Symbol for a door]

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but probably useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31974843/5008845

Comment: thanks @Miki, will try it as soon as I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

I think histograms of gradients (HOG) should work great for such elements.

Comment: i will give HOG a try. FYI I found this [github repo](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG) which gives C++ example code.

Comment: Thanks, it may be useful.