# Issues implementing skeletonize algorithm in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to implement skeletonize alogrithm using opencv. I want to reduce the number of pixels of the below image and make it thin.

**Here is the image which I want to skeletonize**:

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
Mat image = imread("4X4_b9.png",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    int rows = image.rows;
    int cols = image.cols;
    int size = rows * cols;
    Mat skel = Mat::zeros(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8U);
    threshold(image, image, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size(3,3));
    bool done = false;
    while(done == false){
        Mat eroded;
        erode(image, eroded, element);
        Mat temp;
        dilate(eroded, temp, element);
        subtract(image, temp, temp);
        bitwise_or(skel, temp, skel);
        eroded.copyTo(image);

        int zeros = size - countNonZero(image);
        if(zeros == size){
            done = true;
        }
    }

    imshow("skel",skel);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
```

**Note**: I tried this link for reference:
[python implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098888/8327394)

After running this lot of lines are missing.

**Here is the output:**

[image]

What I did wrong ?

Comment: Post your image.

Comment: @zindarod updated.

Comment: You're dilating the original image `dilate(image, temp, element);`. You should be dilating the eroded one `dilate(eroded, temp, element);`.

Comment: I tried your solution. I got some output. But many lines are missing in the output image. Here is the output:
https://ibb.co/iB4DJG

Comment: The code you're copying also gives the same result. If you want a different result, then tweak the algorithm or implement another one.

Comment: any links for other better algorithm ?  @zindarod

Comment: opencv contrib has thinning 
 https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/src/thinning.cpp

Comment: [here](https://github.com/arnaud-ramey/voronoi) you can find another implementation ( i think faster than OpenCV )

Comment: @Xoxo you can find another C++ example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077775/5008845), but probably sturkmen's suggestions are better

Comment: @Miki need your suggestion and ideas on this problem statement genius.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164127/reordering-x-y-coordinates-to-form-a-shape-in-a-particular-pattern

Answer (score -1):

Convert `img` to a black background with white color shape

```
img -> threshold(img, img, 128, 255, THRESHOLD_BINARY_INV);
```