# Recognising and storing shape coordinates from a class diagram in Java

Tags: java, opencv, ocr, shapes

I have been tasked with producing a parametric image processor that is capable of recognising relationships and classes from an image of a class diagram(.jpg, .png etc). I have experimented with OpenCV in Java as a way of detecting shapes and lines within my image. So far I have only produced images with edges detected using methods such as `findContours()`, `drawContours()` and bounding rectangle.

I am looking for a suitable data structure to store the dimensions of shapes and lines(coordinates, area) so that they could be used to reproduce the diagram. As a start I would like to be able to identify primitive shapes such as squares and rectangles in an image such this :

[image: Shapes image]

Any help on how to approach such a problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077775/5008845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting lines and shapes in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974843/detecting-lines-and-shapes-in-opencv-using-python)