# How to distinguish circle from other shapes by using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am fairly newbie in OpenCV and C++. 
And I am stuck at the problem , which might seem like a fairly trivial.

I am trying to distinguish circle from other shapes, such as rectagular, square, triangle, and etc...

This is the code below what I use

```
void setLabel(Mat& image, string str, vector<Point> contour){

int fontface = FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
double scale = 0.5;
int thickness = 1;
int baseline = 0;

Size text = getTextSize(str, fontface, scale, thickness, &baseline);
Rect r = boundingRect(contour);

Point pt(r.x + ((r.width - text.width) / 2), r.y + ((r.height + text.height) / 2));
rectangle(image, pt + Point(0, baseline), pt + Point(text.width, -text.height), CV_RGB(200, 200, 200), CV_FILLED);
putText(image, str, pt, fontface, scale, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), thickness, 8);
```

}

```
int main(){
    Mat img_input, img_result, img_gray;

    String filepath("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\kist\\test.png");
    img_input = imread(filepath, IMREAD_COLOR);

    if (img_input.empty()){
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }          
    cvtColor(img_input, img_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    medianBlur(img_gray, img_gray, 5);

    vector <Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(img_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 200, 50, 0, 0);

    threshold(img_gray, img_gray, 125, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV | THRESH_OTSU);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(img_gray, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    vector<Point2f> approx;
    img_result = img_input.clone();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

        if (fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 0){   

            int size = approx.size();

            if (size % 2 == 0) {
                line(img_result, approx[0], approx[approx.size() - 1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                for (int k = 0; k < size - 1; k++) 
                    line(img_result, approx[k], approx[k + 1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)  
                    circle(img_result, approx[k], 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

                for (size_t j = 0; j < circles.size(); j++) {
                    Vec3i c = circles[j];
                    Point center = Point(c[0], c[1]);

                    circle(img_result, center, 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, LINE_AA);

                    int radius = c[2];

                    circle(img_result, center, radius, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, LINE_AA);

                }

            }

            else if (size % 2 > 0) {
                line(img_result, approx[0], approx[approx.size() - 1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                for (int k = 0; k < size - 1; k++)
                    line(img_result, approx[k], approx[k + 1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                    circle(img_result, approx[k], 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

            }

            if (size == 3)
                setLabel(img_result, "triangle", contours[i]);


            else if (size == 4 && isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                setLabel(img_result, "rectangle", contours[i]); 

            else if (size == 5 && isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                setLabel(img_result, "pentagon", contours[i]); 

            else if (size == 6 && isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                setLabel(img_result, "hexagon", contours[i]);  

            else if (size == 10 && isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                setLabel(img_result, "decagon", contours[i]);   

            else {
                setLabel(img_result, to_string(approx.size()), contours[i]);                        
            }
        } 
        else if (fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) == 0) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
                Vec3i c = circles[i];
                Point center = Point(c[0], c[1]);

                circle(img_result, center, 2, Scalar(0, 100, 100), 2, LINE_AA);

                int radius = c[2];

                circle(img_result, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2, LINE_AA);

            }
            setLabel(img_result, to_string(approx.size()), contours[i]);
        }
    }

    imshow("input", img_input);
    imshow("result", img_result);
```

And as shown in the figure below, I was able to find out vertex of each figure and draw lines.

However, I want to remove the vertex and straight lines and leave the circle outline from circle shape. And further, I would like to describe the circle shape as 'circle' and count the number of each shape.

Please help me ~~

Thanks a ton !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLszP.png)

[image]

Comment: Please attach the original image as well

Comment: Hello ZdaR, I attached the original image Thanks alot.

Comment: What exactly do you want in output ?

Comment: Actually I would like to draw only circle outline on the circle without the vertex and 8 straight lines.

Comment: However, as you can see the figure, circle shape has vertex, straight line, and circle outline at the same time.

Comment: And further, I would like to count the number of each shape

Comment: That is because you are calling `line()` and `circle()` in your code within a `for` loop. Disabling those lines would remove the labelling of vertices and lines from your output.

Comment: What do you mean by *count the number of each shape*

Comment: Thanks for reply and which lines do I have to remove from the code?

counting number of each shape means that literally find out how many circle, rectangle, and triangle shapes exist in this picture

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077775/5008845). You can use a metric called _"circularity"_ as explained there

Comment: hi Miki, I really appreciate your reply, It helped a lot. Thank you. I will apply those comments later. Actually, I just changed conditions for if statement and position of the 'for loop'. Finally, I made it !! Thank you