# Classify hand drawn shapes with opencv

Tags: opencv, contour, feature-extraction

I have been coding with OpenCV lately,

I have drawn on a paper few shapes (circle, triangle , rectangle, square, Parallelogram),
and would like to classify the shapes according to their characteristics.

I have searched for contours and drew them, and moreover drew the minAreaRect for each shape.

I tried using the function matchShapes but it didn't give me the result I had expected, 
I have tried using Polygon Approximations but it seems it to fail here too.

(I went through all questions here before posting this question)

**Original image**
[image: Original image]
**After some processing**
[image: After some processing]

What should be the correct approach for classifying hand-drawn shapes?

Any tips/suggestions would be great, I'm stuck :/.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077775/5008845