# OpenCV detect hand-drawn circles, ellipses and pentagons

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision, shapes

I'm developing an Android drawing application and i'm struggling on detecting circles and pentagon. 
I've tried to use circularity as described here: [Detecting lines and shapes in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974843/detecting-lines-and-shapes-in-opencv-using-python/32077775#32077775) but without result (pentagon has a circularity very close to a circle or an ellipse). Currently i'm using SimpleBlobDetector but it doesn't detect properly ellipses and sometimes detect pentagon as Blob. 
Here the
[image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdj0o.png): the pentagon on the right is detected but not the ellipse on the bottom
.
 *BlobDetectorParams*:

```
            blobDetectorParams.set_filterByInertia(true);
            blobDetectorParams.set_filterByCircularity(true);
            blobDetectorParams.set_filterByConvexity(true);
            blobDetectorParams.set_filterByArea(false);

            blobDetectorParams.set_minInertiaRatio(0.01F);

            blobDetectorParams.set_minCircularity(0.8F);

            blobDetectorParams.set_minConvexity(0.87F);

            blobDetectorParams.set_minThreshold(0);
            blobDetectorParams.set_maxThreshold(300);
            blobDetectorParams.set_thresholdStep(10);
            blobDetectorParams.set_minRepeatability(1);
```

Comment: those aren't "blobs" as commonly understood in image processing.

Comment: So what can I do to detect drawn circles and ellipses? Currently i can only detect the others shapes (triangle, square ecc)

Comment: How do you detect triangles and squares? If you use contours try the following: To detect a circle/ellipse compare the contour area against the ellipse-area of the minAreaRect around the contour (rectange width/height are the ellipse radii and rectangle center is the ellipse center). Also have a look at "contour moments".

Comment: To detect triangles, squares ecc just use findcontours and approxPolyDP with 
epsilon = 0.03*arcLenght(contours), this do the trick for all the shapes (drawn and not). The problem is with circles/ellipses because the detected points can be 4,5,6 ecc but i noticed that most of times the detect points are > 6. I used your suggestion in a different way: just use the boundingbox and check for the squareness: if it's less than 0.2 is a square, else is an ellipse 
(squareness = Math.abs(bounds.width() - bounds.height()) / Math.max(bounds.width(), bounds.height())